# Que tipo de variable es un DNI en JAVA?

Tags: java, variables

Se formula la siguiente pregunta: 
NO HAY ALGÚN TIPO DE DATO QUE ALMACENE DATOS DE NUMEROS Y LETRAS A LA VEZ?

DNI - 01234567A

1- Tipo de variable más óptimo.
2-Declaración de la variable
3-Inicialización de la variable

---

En mi opinión he hecho esto:

```
package com.mycompany.ejercicios;

/**
 *
 * @author Wallcodes
 */
public class ej9 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero_dni = 12345678;
        String letra_dni = "-X";
        System.out.println(numero_dni + letra_dni);   
    }   
}
```

De modo que no tenga que crear dos variables (int y String).

---

Tras estar leyendo y después de preguntar en la comunidad, sin descartar la posiblidad tan obvia de que sea la variable de tipo String, lo que ocurría era que no estaba introduciendo bien los datos. No estoy familiarizado con Netbeans y me he liado un poco. Todo solucionado. Gracias a todos!

Comment: porqué no pornerlo en un string directamente? string dni="123456789XX"

Comment: Un DNI es un String, porque es un tipo de dato alfanumérico. Generalmente si una variable no va a contener en exclusiva números se declara como String.

Comment: Si, correcto, tecnicamente se corresponde para el tipo de datos que puede almacenar, pero en Netbeans al crear la variable, me lo marca como error. No deja deja compilarlo, es bastante raro, y mira que es bien sencillo... ajjaaj gracias de antemano.

Comment: @wallcodes dónde marca error y qué error marca?

Comment: Tampoco está mal tener un String o un Char con la letra y un entero con el número. Depende de lo que hagas con el DNI. Si por ejemplo solo lees el DNI y lo escribes en pantalla sin hacer nada más con él, yo elegiría un String. Pero si tienes que realizar un cálculo para validar si la letra del DNI es correcta, yo preferiría tener un entero para el número y un String o Char para la letra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el DNI yo siempre uso String ya que te permite usar numeros y letras incluso si necesitas la separación también te permite añadirla:

```
String dni = "11111111-N"
```

En caso de necesitar letra o numero por separado es tan sencillo como usar la función de split()

Comment: Si, correcto, tecnicamente se corresponde para el tipo de datos que puede almacenar, pero en Netbeans al crear la variable, me lo marca como error. No deja deja compilarlo, es bastante raro, y mira que es bien sencillo... ajjaaj gracias de antemano. Estoy aprendiendo java... yo soy amante de php la verdad.

Comment: ¿Que error te da?

Comment: Madre de mi vida..... osea no me lo puedo creer, ha sido crear la publicacion y coger tu comentario pegarlo, y funciona...Te puedes creer que llevo 1 hora mirando y leyendo por internet sobre los tipos de datos convenido que no era String...y ahora no me error... seguro que algo habia puesto mal. Muchas gracias!!!